# Question about facebook Secure Canvas Page

Tags: facebook, canvas

Wonder if I need to install SSL on my web machine that user can see my application on secure mode (HTTPS)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YES, they load an iframe via https from the url you provide.